# Need a VB Script to check if service exist

Tags: vbscript

I want to write a VBS script which will check if specific service is installed/exist or not locally.

If it is not installed/exist, script will display message (any text) and disabled the network interface i.e. NIC.

If service exist and running, NO Action. Just exit.

If service exist but not running, same action, script will display message (any text) and disabled the network interface i.e. NIC.

i have below given code which is displaying a message in case one service is stop but it is not -

1. Checking if service exist or not
2. Disabling the NIC

   ```
   strComputer = "."
   Set objWMIService = Getobject("winmgmts:"_
       & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
   Set colRunningServices = onjWMIService.ExecQuery _
       ("select State from Win32_Service where Name = 'dhcp'")

   For Each objService in colRunningServices
       If objService.State <> "Running" Then
           errReturn = msgbox ("Stopped")
       End If
   Next
   ```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is this tagged `VB.NET`?

Comment: Tomalak, i have removed the VB.net tag. Thanks !

Comment: Please take a step back an describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you want to achieve by doing this?

Answer (score 0):

To know if service is installed, check `colRunningServices.Count` . It will be 0 if no service match the wmi query.

To disable NIC, use a wmi query `SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter`, iterate de returned collection of NICs, find the one you are interested and use the Disable/Enable method of it. BUT this only will work if OS is Vista or later.

Comment: Thanks MC ND, for the information. I am not that good with scripting. I know i am asking much and being greedy, but can you please provide me it in form of ready to use code ?

Comment: It's imposible to me to provide you with a ready to use code. While service detection is straighforward, NICs are a different beast. I don't know anything about your NIC configuration, enabled / disabled existing cards, NICS names, .... there are a lot of detail to take in consideration. Sorry, but you should have to done it yourself or ask for specific tasks.

Answer (score 0):

It would look something like this **but I cannot test this!**

```
Option Explicit

Const TITLE = "Title"
Const SERVICE = "dhcp"
Dim wmi
Dim svcs,svc

Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set svcs = wmi.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Service where Name = '" & SERVICE & "'")

If svcs.Count = 0 Then
  Call MsgBox(SERVICE & " service does not exist",vbCritical,TITLE)
  Call disableNIC(wmi)
Else
  For Each svc In svcs
    If svc.State <> "Running" Then
      Call MsgBox(SERVICE & " service is not running",vbCritical,TITLE)
      Call disableNIC(wmi)
    End If
  Next
End If

Set wmi = Nothing
WScript.Quit

Sub disableNIC(ByRef wmi)
  Dim nics,nic
  Set nics = wmi.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapter")
  For Each nic In nics
    nic.Disable
  Next
End Sub
```

Beware that this disables every NIC. If you want to specify one you'd have to add a `where` clause in `disableNIC`. Also I imagine you would have to run this as an administrator.

Seems like a weird thing to want to do though...